# Windows Vista can only boot into safe mode

Tags: windows-vista, boot, troubleshooting

I've got a Dell XPS M1730 that will only boot into safe mode. Since I get a black screen when windows should load after the BIOS loads. I suspect this is a software problem only since I can boot into safe mode but when I try to do system recovery and restore when I restore I get the same error that windows just won't load. Could you tell me what I should do about this?

Thank you

Comment: have you tried running check disk in safe mode?

Comment: I tried running check disk but it won't complete and it compliains about the temperature being too high.

Comment: @NickRosencrantz If it says the temperature is too high, what do you think would be the issue? Is it Windows telling you this, or some obscure program?

Comment: @Luke it's actually the boot sequence at start that reports that the system got too hot and therefore was powered off so it's an official message. I spoke with Dell support and they said that this computer had been overheating before and had service for it so I can hand it to their repair unit since there seems to be both an overheating problem and an issue with bad hard drive cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To manual repair the system when in safe mode do a system file check,

**sfc /scannow**

this will check consistence of system files and repair them if errors are found.
If errors are reported but not could not be fixed on first run sfc can be run two or three times.

If there are errors that sfc cannot fix an inplace reinstallation (run setup.exe from installation DVD while in safe mode) will refresh the system. User files and installed programs will not be touched but all Windows updates have to be downloaded and installed again later.